# Where did this nav color come from?

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm working on a site that someone else worked on before me, and I have to replicate the navigation that they made, but I can't find anywhere in the source what they used for the nav background.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/47171002/Untitled.png

The problem is that I looked through the source and I can't find it anywhere. It isn't a picture in the resources, it isn't in the HTML, and it isn't in the CSS.

So how did that nav color get there?

The site is www.allaboutwinecellars.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
body
{
    background:url(../images/body_bg.gif) repeat-x;
    ...
}
```

The color comes from a horizontally repeated background.

Comment: Ohhhh, I was only looking for a picture the size of the navbar, but I see now. Thanks so much

Answer (score 3):

It's in the background, on the body:

http://www.allaboutwinecellars.com/images/body_bg.gif

Answer (score 0):

its background img in you body css 
http://www.allaboutwinecellars.com/images/body_bg.gif

If you don't know how to debug css/html. use [firebug extension](http://www.getfirebug.com) with your firefox to debug styles on your web page.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they an in-line style that specifies a background image for each nave node on **hover** or **active**:

```
background-image:url(http://www.allaboutwinecellars.com/images/nave_hover.gif); "
```

And a general repeating background image as the background:

```
body
{
    background:url(../images/body_bg.gif) repeat-x;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it come from

```
body {
    background: url("../images/body_bg.gif") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #000000;}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a nav_hover.gif somewhere for when it is over.

And that background is from http://www.allaboutwinecellars.com/images/body_bg.gif (at the bottom.)